# accumulator as counter in spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using spark streaming and I want to make an accumulator that counts the number of instances of a dstream so far. I want to increase the counter inside the train method and then I want to use this counter in another method named assign. The code posted bellow does not work. I cannot find the named accumulator in sparks UI and when I print its value outside the method is always zero.  If you think there is a more proper way to do it (I mean not with an accumulator) please explain me how.

```
var numInstances: LongAccumulator = null

def init(ssc:StreamingContext) : Unit = {
numInstances = ssc.sparkContext.longAccumulator("numInst")
}

def train(input: DStream[Example]): Unit = {
input.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  rdd.foreach(ex => {
    manager = manager.update(ex)
    numInstances.add(1) 
   })
})
}

def assign: Array[Example] = {
 if(numInstances.value <= sizeOption.getValue) {
  //do something
 }
 else {
  //do something else
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the function passed to `foreachRDD` is executed on the driver, you can re-write `train` in this way:

```
var totalCount = 0L
def train(input: DStream[Example]): Unit = {
  input.foreachRDD { rdd =>
   totalCount += rdd.count() 
   rdd.foreach { ex =>
     manager = manager.update(ex)
   }
  }
}
```

Be careful with `totalCount` value - changes are not distributed by Spark and valid only on driver, so you can't use it in code running on executors.